# Trouble with method subtraction c#

Tags: c#, methods, subtraction

I am experiencing some difficulty with method. My code seems to work just fine until I reach my formula for method. I have done something similar I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong. It is the portion that has yearsToWork.

```
int age;
int yearsToWork;

Console.Write("Enter your name:");
string name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Enter your age:");
age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

yearsToWork = 65 - age;
Console.Write("\nYou will work:", yearsToWork);
Console.Write("years before you retire.");
Console.Read();
```

Thank-you for the assistance.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: See the documentation for `Console.Write()`; the parameters don't mean what you think they mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int age;
        int YearsToWork;

        Console.Write("Enter your name:");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter your age:");
        age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        YearsToWork = 65 - age;
        Console.WriteLine("You will work: {0} years before you retire", YearsToWork);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Console.WriteLine(); work similar to string.Format(); when inserting a string;

 The 1st parameter after the string will be {0}, second string {1} and so on...

Comment: Yes it did work, thank-you so much! Also, thank-you for explaining it. I'm still fairly new to C# and now I understand it a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Console.Write("\nYou will work: " + YearsToWork.ToString());
```

As MSDN says, `Console.Write`:

> Writes the text representation of the specified object to the standard
>   output stream using the specified format information.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xdyw6yk(v=vs.110).aspx

And that might not be the value you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are calling `Console.Write("\nYou will work:", YearsToWork);` which only writes the `string` and nothing else, if you wanted to generate a more elaborate message you should use [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx). Your code should be something like this:

```
int maxWorkAge = 65;
Console.Write("Enter your name:");

string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter your age:");
int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int yearsToWork = maxWorkAge - age;

Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("You will work: {0} years before you retire.", yearsToWork);
Console.Read();
```

Notice that I have set all variable names to *lowerCamelCase* and declared them as needed, also I made a variable (which could as well be a constant) for the `65` constant you were using. All these are best practice recomendations. Hope this helps